# How to autoload .trs file in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, online-store

I am creating an online store. Every hour, the database with goods in .trs format, which is needed for almost everything in this very online store, is uploaded to the root of the site. I see two options:

1) Load the database in phpmyadmin, but how to do it automatically, for example, I did not find every hour.

2) Read the .trs file directly through php, which seems like a pretty bad and insecure idea to me.

Actually, the question is: how to automatically load a database dump in phpmyadmin?

Here is example of  [.trs file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DSDLsAIQ_Jzj_2eEBUSYwbY8EMaO3aeM)

Comment: What you have try?

Comment: can't you just read it in php? is PHPmyadmin a requirement?

Comment: You do realise that `phpMyAdmin` is a tool written in PHP and NOT A DBMS dont you? MySQL is the DBMS

Comment: ___Is it just me?___ The term a `.trs` file means nothing special to me, is that something specific/special/significant

Comment: @JoSSte Any option is right for me.

Comment: Can you show an sensible example of the `.trs` file please

Comment: @RiggsFolly Of course I can

Comment: @RiggsFolly  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DSDLsAIQ_Jzj_2eEBUSYwbY8EMaO3aeM

Comment: So a `.trs` file is a `csv` file basically. You can load that using the MySQL [`LOAD DATA.....`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) run from a CRON job once an hour. Or you could write a PHP script. My Prefered way would be the PHP script (also run from a CRON) as you have more control over hiccups